# unable to understand the row or column sum matrix problem

Tags: c, matrix

**I am new here can anyone solve this problem because I didn't understand this question which column and row sum happen???**

Row or Column sum

John likes to play with numbers. He is playing a game where he writes numbers starting 1 till N in multiple rows. Initially he chooses a number W and he writes W numbers in each row except probably in the last row when he is done writing till number N. Given N and W and any row or column in this arrangement, print the sum of all the numbers in this row or column.

Input

First line of input will contain a number T = number of test cases. For each test case, the first line will contain two numbers N and W. Another line will contain a number X and letter 'R' or 'C' separated by space. If letter is 'R', print the sum of numbers in row number X , else if letter is 'C', print the sum of numbers in column number X. Rows and columns are numbered in 1-based index ( as 1,2,3,..)

Output

For each test case, print the sum of numbers in the row or column on a single line.
Sample Input

2

5 2

2 C

10  3

4  R

Sample Output

6

10

Comment: If you didn't understand the question, [maybe this will help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sM0Le.png).

Comment: thanks for helping now I understand the question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to - sum of matrix elements using file lock (unix - C/C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109000/how-to-sum-of-matrix-elements-using-file-lock-unix-c-c)